# (C++) Why does the '||' logical operator gives back 1?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C++. Why does this code gives me back '1' when I write it out?

`cout << (false||(!false));`

It writes out '1', which is equivalent with 'true'.

Why does it give back true instead of false? How does it decide whether the statement is true or not?

Comment: @tibiv111 To be or not to be that is the question.:)

Comment: Did you want `cout << std::boolalpha << (false || (!false));`?  I'm not sure what your "Why?" is asking for/about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How does it decide whether the statement is true or not?

The boolean operators follow the rules of boolean algebra.

The `!` operator (*not*) corresponds to logical negation. Result is false if operand is true and true if operand is false.

The `||` (*inclusive or*) operator corresponds to logical (inclusive) disjunction. The result is false only if both operands are false. Otherwise result is true.

The output is 1, because the standard output stream produces the character 1 when you insert a true bool (unless the `std::ios_base::boolalpha` format flag is set).

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
cout << (false||(!false));
```

Evaluates to:

```
cout << (false||(true));
```

Which evaluates to:

```
cout << true;
```

Since `false || true` is `true`. The C++ representation of `true` is generally `1`, as opposed to `0` for `false`, at least by convention.

Comment: This is not about machine representations. The bit representation of `true` is up to the implementation. The standard, however, mandates that you get a `1` when you _convert_ a bool to an int.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps I used that term too loosely, so that's a good clarification.

Comment: It's still misleading, unfortunately! The _representation_ could be 97437652, per C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Would "generally" suffice? I've never seen it as anything but, yet you're right, someone could get...creative.

Comment: It would be easier to just make a statement about bool converting to int (see how eerorika did it), but your answer is now at least factually correct, thanks :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's technically no conversion to int involved in the example. There is an overload for inserting the bool directly. The implementor may of course take advantage of the conversion rule when implementing the stream operation.

Comment: @eerorika You speak the truth

Answer (score 5):

Because `false` or not `false` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Think about your `if` statement ...

Your test value is a `boolean` so it is either `true` or `false`. Now look at your `if`:

```
if (false || (!false))
```

You are saying:

> The test result is true if:
>
> 1. The test value is `false` **or**
> 2. The test value is **not** `false` (thus `true`).

So either way, the `if` returns `true` whether it is `true` or `false`.